# PHP object has semicolon (or other strange character) in variable name

Tags: php, xml, variables, escaping

I've got an object, which contains semicolons in the property names, when I var_dump, I get:

```
object(Sales) {

    [thisisa:propertyname] => 'some value'

}
```

So, how do I access the property? $object->thisisa:propertyname throws an error. I read somewhere a while ago you can wrap thisisa:propertyname in some characters (I've tried {, [, (, |) but I can't remember which.

Also, it seems that using:

```
$var = "thisisa:propertyname";
$object->$$var;
```

Doesn't work either.

Help!

Mike

Comment: just a bit of pedantry- : is a colon. ; is a semicolon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
echo $object->{'thisisa:propertyname'};
```

Also, For [variable member variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), one `$` is enough. So

```
$attr = "thisisa:propertyname";
echo $object->$attr;
```

Comment: Don’t forget the quotes: `$object->{'thisisa:propertyname'}` or `$object->{"thisisa:propertyname"}`.